# Page Refresh Issue (F5)

Tags: asp.net

I have a page on which i have only one TextBox say **Comments** and **Post Comment** Button.

Now during input user write something in Comments textbox and press Post Comment button. Whatever is written in the textbox all get stored in database and i clear the textbox with

```
textbox.text = string.empty statement.
```

After this user press F5 without doing anything and the same comment which i have already cleared gets stored in the database again. I want to keep track of this thing that when button event is fired on F5 should not do anything. please help in this.

Comment: is there any ajax going on, or after user submits its comment you just refresh the page?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're doing the database insert on an event handler for the Post Comment button. If you're doing it in `Page_Load`, or some other method that's called by the framework on every rendering of the page, then this would result in the duplicate inserts you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read up on the
[Post/Redirect/Get Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

After performing the database submission you need to send a redirect back to the user which causes the browser to make a second request and eliminates the possibility of a duplicate post back if they refresh the browser. The redirect URL can be the same page you started on which you noted is one of the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

After inserting to the database, redirect to another page.

Comment: But the requirement is that we have to be on the same page

Comment: redirect to the same page then!

Answer (score 0):

This is a browser's issue. You click on your button and save data into DB in your button's handler but when you is clicking F5 after, browser asks you (not all browsers is asking): do you want to send same postback? You say Yes and browser **sends same postback with same information** to server. Server checks this postback and does Post Comment action where you save info into DB again.

Comment: this should be a comment, not answer

Answer (score 0):

There are some examples with source code how you detect refresh of the page to avoid double submition

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/DetectingRefresh_.aspx

http://dotnetslackers.com/community/blogs/simoneb/archive/2007/01/06/Using-an-HttpModule-to-detect-page-refresh.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Most simple solution (after Redirect) is using Session variable to count number of "post backs":

```
int postBackCount = (Session["postbacks"] == null) ? 0 : (int)Session["postbacks"];
if (Page.IsPostBack) {
    if (postBackCount >= 1) {
        lbError.Text = "Can't submit this more than once, sorry";
    }
    else {
        //do DB stuff here.....
    }
    Session["postbacks"] = postBackCount + 1;
}
else {
    Session["postbacks"] = 0;
}
```