# Button click handler executes when a web form pages is refreshed

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, event-handling, refresh, page-refresh

In a VB.Net code-behind file we have a few button-click handlers.

I noticed that if the user clicks a button a button handler will execute. We noticed something unexpected. If the user clicks the Refresh button on the browser the same button handler that previously executed will execute again even though the user did not click on any buttons on the web form.

Is there a way to stop the execution of the button click handlers when the user refreshes the web form page?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232715/page-refresh-issue-f5

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply. After reading the post you gave a link for I found something mentioned about doing a page redirect and found if I used this redirect coding to redirect my same page after doing the code in the handler, refreshing the page did not make the code execute again. Here is the actual coding I used:  Response.Redirect("Beverages.aspx") Thanks again. :-)